# Proving sets are Borel sets

Tags: real-analysis, borel-sets, borel-measures

Suppose $f,g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow [0, +\infty]$ are Borel measurable functions. Consider the sets $A = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | f(x) < g(x)\}$ and $B = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | f(x) = g(x)\}$. Are either of these sets Borel sets?

I'm still quite new to Borel-$\sigma$-algebras. I thought of proving that these sets were either open or closed or could be written as an interval, but I wasn't able to get really far. Any hints are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

1)
$$\{x\mid f(x)<g(x)\}=\bigcup_{r\in \mathbb Q}\{x\mid f(x)<r\}\cap \{x\mid g(x)>r\}.$$

2. $$\{x\mid f(x)=g(x)\}=\{x\mid f(x)<g(x)\}^c\cup\{x\mid g(x)<f(x)\}^c.$$

Comment: Tell me if I'm on the right track:
1) If we can somehow write these sets as open sets, then the union is Borel as $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable?
2) because we know from 1) that that set is Borel, so is its complement and the union of borel sets is borel?

Comment: 1) No (these sets won't be open). 2) Yes. @Geigercounter

Comment: Then I'm quite stuck on how I could prove that the union in 1) is Borel...

Comment: What mean $f$ and $g$ being Borel measurable ? @Geigercounter

Comment: that the inverse map of a Borel set is Borel

Comment: Exactly. So, what can you conclude ? @Geigercounter

Comment: I'm still stuck on this question...

Comment: Since $f$ and $g$ are Borel measurable, then $\{x\mid f(x)<r\}$ and $\{x\mid g(x)>r\}$ are Borels sets...

Comment: The equality in 2) is wrong, the left side doesn't need a complement @Surb

Comment: @Geigercounter: Indeed, thank you for pointing out this point. I edited the answer.